# Sharing file through Google Drive with user on another domain without sending notification

Tags: google-drive-api

Our application has requirement of programatically sharing files in google drive with users on another domain (say yahoo.com) without sending a notification through Drive. However, it is observed that Drive does not allow sharing of files with users on other domains without sending an email notification. Is there a solution available?

```
    Permission permission=new Permission();
    permission.setValue(emailId);
    permission.setType("user");
    permission.setRole("reader");
    SERVICE.permissions().insert(fileId, permission).setSendNotificationEmails(true).execute();
```

Above is our code which sets parameter setSendNotificationEmails as true because a false value is not allowed for emails outside of google domains.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: What programming language are you using? This is how I was able to do it in python 'service.permissions().insert(fileId='<fileId>',  sendNotificationEmails=False, body=body).execute()'.  Check if adding that parameter in the insert method helps.

Comment: Hi Gerardo, I am developing the application using Java. Method suggested by you works only if both the document owner and recipient are on Google domain. If the recipient is on another domain (say yahoo), setting setNotificationEmails to true becomes mandatory.

Comment: You are right. It turned out that the other domain where I tried is also a Google account and that's why it worked. After trying with a non Google account I got: "Bad Request. User message: 'You are trying to invite <non Google email>. Since there is no Google account associated with this email address, you must check the "Notify people" box to invite this recipient.'" It makes sense sending the email is enforced, since accounts outside Google don't have Drive, and they wouldn't have another way to know that they have access to the file.

Comment: Yes. We intend to send a custom email whenever a file is shared but given this constraint recipient receives two emails, one the custom email from our application and another one from Google Drive which is not desirable.